# Upload and update excel file

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a task to upload the excel file and also check update if the same record found, I have uploaded the excel file in the database which is working fine.

Now, I have to check if the same records inserted then update otherwise insert the new records, I have two table  first I am inserting the records in the temp table  then after that I am checking the temp table with the original table , if records matches then update  else insert, I am using nested for loop to check the records
my loop works fine and insert the top two records, but when it comes to the 3rd record then insert it multiple times and on 4th again multiple times,Kindly guide me what i am doing wrong
here is my code so far

```
       protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int id;
        string contactPerson;
        string designation;
        string company;
        string contact;
        string emailaddress;
        string city;
        string region;
        string industry;
        string division;
        string mobile;
        string address;

        string path = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
        path = path.Replace(" ", "");

        FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/uploadExcel/") + FileUpload1.FileName);
        String ExcelPath = Server.MapPath("~/uploadExcel/") + FileUpload1.FileName;
        OleDbConnection mycon = new OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = " + ExcelPath + "; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0; Persist Security Info = False");

        mycon.Open();

       DeleteRecords();

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", mycon);
        OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            if (dr[0].ToString() != "")
            {
                // Response.Write("<br/>"+dr[0].ToString());
                id = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString());
                contactPerson = dr[1].ToString();
                designation = dr[2].ToString();
                company = dr[3].ToString();
                emailaddress = dr[4].ToString();
                contact = dr[5].ToString();
                mobile = dr[6].ToString();
                address = dr[7].ToString();
                city = dr[8].ToString();
                region = dr[9].ToString();
                industry = dr[10].ToString();
                division = dr[11].ToString();

                InsertTemp(id, contactPerson, designation, company, emailaddress, contact,
                 mobile, address, city, region, industry, division);

                //InsertOrignal(id, contactPerson, designation, company, emailaddress, contact,
                // mobile, address, city, region, industry, division);

            }

            else
            {
                break;
            }


            String myconn = "Data Source=Ali-PC;Initial Catalog=MushkhoApp;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myconn);
            conn.Open();
            DataTable dt_temp = new DataTable();
            DataTable dt_orignal = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da_temp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Tbl_ExcelData order by id asc", conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da_orignal = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Tbl_ExcelUploadData order by id asc", conn);

            da_temp.Fill(dt_temp);
            da_orignal.Fill(dt_orignal);


            if (dt_orignal.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < dt_temp.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < dt_orignal.Rows.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if (dt_temp.Rows[i]["email"].ToString() == dt_orignal.Rows[j]["email"].ToString())
                        {
                            //Update Record if required
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //insert record into orignal table


                            InsertOrignal(id, contactPerson, designation, company, emailaddress, contact, mobile, address, city, region, industry, division);


                        }
                    }

                }
            }

            else
            {
                InsertOrignal(id, contactPerson, designation, company, emailaddress, contact, mobile, address, city, region, industry, division);

            }

        }

       lblmessage.Text = "Data Has Been Updated Successfully";

        mycon.Close();
        File.Delete(ExcelPath);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }



}



private void InsertTemp(int id, String contactPerson, String designation, String company, String emailaddress, 
                             String contact, String mobile, String address,String city,String region,String industry,
                             String division)
{


    //String mycon = "Data Source=Ali-PC;Initial Catalog=MushkhoApp;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(mycon);
    con.Open();




            string query = "insert into Tbl_ExcelData (id,contactperson,designation,company,email,contact,mobile,address,city,region,industry,division) values('" + id + "','" + contactPerson + "', '" + designation + "','" + company + "','" + emailaddress + "','" + contact + "','" + mobile + "','" + address + "','" + city + "','" + region + "','" + industry + "','" + division + "')";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }


private void InsertOrignal(int id, String contactPerson, String designation, String company, String emailaddress,
                            String contact, String mobile, String address, String city, String region, String industry,
                            String division)
{


    //String mycon = "Data Source=Ali-PC;Initial Catalog=MushkhoApp;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(mycon);
    con.Open();




    string query = "insert into Tbl_ExcelUploadData (id,contactperson,designation,company,email,contact,mobile,address,city,region,industry,division) values('" + id + "','" + contactPerson + "', '" + designation + "','" + company + "','" + emailaddress + "','" + contact + "','" + mobile + "','" + address + "','" + city + "','" + region + "','" + industry + "','" + division + "')";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = query;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}


private void DeleteRecords()
{

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(mycon);
    con.Open();
    string query = "Delete from Tbl_ExcelData";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = query;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}


 }
```

Comment: Once you upload the data from excel to temp table then it may be easier/better to handle the reconciliation (update or insert) between two tables using a simple SQL procedure call rather than doing it record by record from the application.

Comment: I am with @RajeshBhat but to answer your question: The problem: you keep reading and comparing all records from `da_temp` for each row you insert into your `InsertTemp`. Solution: You need to read excel and insert all records first and only then start comparison process. Hint: your while loop should end right after the first `else` statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Temporary table just to check if the row exists in an Original table, then it is not a good practice.

Directly check if the row exists in your original table with the Primary key `id`  or any `Unique Key` and then decide whether to `Insert` or `Update`.

One way to do this,

```
while (dr.Read()) 
{
    if (dr[0].ToString() != "") 
    {
       id = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString());        //add other columns which needs to be fetched from Excel
       string query = "select count(1) from Tbl_ExcelData where id=?";        //To check if the row already exsits    
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(con);

       cmd.CommandText = query;
       cmd.Paramaters.Add(new SqlParameter(1, id));

       int count = (Int32) cmd.ExecuteScalar();

       if (count > 0) //which means row already exists
       {
          //Your update code goes here
       } 
       else 
       {
            InsertOrignal(id, contactPerson, designation, company, emailaddress, contact, mobile, address, city, region, industry, division);
       }
}
```

After comments, here is a basic idea. One way you can load your excel data into `DataTable` and loop through it and decide for `Upsert`. Remember to learn about [MultipleActiveResultSets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-multiple-active-result-sets)

```
try
{
    string ExcelPath = Server.MapPath("~/uploadExcel/") + FileUpload1.FileName;
    string _oleDBConnectionString = string.Format("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = {0}; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0; Persist Security Info = False", ExcelPath);
    string _sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=Ali-PC;Initial Catalog=MushkhoApp;Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"; //enable MultipleActiveResultSets as you'll be opening a nested SqlConnection
    string _excelQuery = "select * from [Sheet1$]";
    DataTable tempDataTable = null;

    using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(_oleDBConnectionString)) //This code loads your excel data into data table
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(_excelQuery, conn))
        {
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
               var dt = new DataTable();

               dt.Load(reader); //this will load your excel data into DataTable

               tempDataTable = dt;
            }
        }
    }

    using(var sqlConn = new SqlConnection(_sqlConnectionString)) //this code will connect to sql db and upsert based on the id from the excel
    {
        sqlConn.Open();

        string countQuery = "select count(1) from Tbl_ExcelData where id=:id";    

        using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(countQuery, sqlConn))
        {
            var param = new SqlParameter("@id");

            foreach (DataRow row in tempDataTable.Rows) //this will loop through the DataTable rows, the actual rows from Excel which are loaded into DataTable
            {
                var id = row["id"]; //get the id column from the excel
                var contactPerson = row["contactPerson"]; //get the contactPerson column from the excel

                cmd.Paramaters["@id"] =  id;

                int count = (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                if (count) //row already exist in original table
                {
                    //update the row in original table
                }
                else
                {
                    //insert the row in original table
                    InsertOriginal(sqlConn, id, contactPerson);
                }
            }               
        }
     }
 }
 catch(Exception ex)
 {
 }

function InsertOriginal(SqlConnection conn, int id, string contactPerson)
{
    string insertQuery = "insert into Tbl_ExcelUploadData (id,contactpersonn) values('@id','@contactPerson');

    using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn))
     {
         cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id",id));
         cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@contactPerson", contactPerson));
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
}
```

Also, this is not a tested code. Feel free to comment back.

Comment: I am not inserting the records directly to the original table, first inserting it in the temp table and after that matching the temp table with the original table. Is this a good approach? and also on the basis of email id i am matching the records because email id is unique in the data

Comment: No, it is not a good approach to insert into temp tables just to compare with your original tables. Just check the condition directly before inserting into Original table. Check the updated code

Comment: Also guide me  the good way to upload and update the excel file

Comment: @mbhthiaranidharan88, the code works fine, just wanted to know about the insert  query will this insert the record one by one or all in once

Comment: one last thing to ask, when inserting the records it says 
Column 'contactPerson' does not belong to table  can you guide me  to insert, because i have the column in my table with the name contactPerson, as I shared the code before

Comment: It clearly says that `contact Person` is not available in your table

Comment: I understand that  but the excel file contain the column name contact Person and  the records in the datatable also shows a column name contact Person,
but on insert it shows the error

Comment: This is how I am inserting the record
   string query = "insert into Tbl_ExcelData (id,contactPerson,designation) values('" + id + "','" + tempDataTable.Rows[0]["contactPerson"] + "', '" + tempDataTable.Rows[0]["designation"] + "','")